# What are the Google Chrome defined APIs?

Tags: android, google-chrome

While fiddling with /data/data/ files for the Google Chrome app I found this interesting README file

> Google Chrome settings and storage represent user-selected preferences
>   and information and MUST not be extracted, overwritten or modified
>   except through Google Chrome defined APIs.

What do they mean by the Google Chrome defined API and is there actually a way to modify the user settings for the app through code?

Comment: `/data/data` sounds like you're referring specifically to the Android app -- is that correct?

Comment: Yes I added the android tag again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the APIs are listed [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index). The README is a friendly reminder that if your code messes around with Chrome, you're violating your developer agreement, unless you're doing it with those APIs. An example might be an executable that finds the raw preferences file and alters it.

Comment: Actually I was speaking the Android app (the tag was there) and there is no way to access the JavaScript APIs since there is no add-on development on Chrome for Android.

Comment: I see. Then my answer is correct, but unfortunately, as you say, there aren't any extensions on Chrome for Android, so the "unless" part doesn't help you.

Comment: What developer agreement?  Surely, someone can write an app external to Chromium that doesn't require signing a Google developer agreement.